# Type mismatch using trim_end_matches as closure function: expected signature ... found signature of "for<'r> ..."

Tags: rust, char, ascii, predicate

I have the code below to do a word count in which punctuation is ignored.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn word_count(words: &str) -> HashMap<String, u32> {
    let mut hm: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
    words
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|word| word.trim_end_matches(char::is_ascii_punctuation))
        .map(|word| {
            hm.entry(word.to_string())
                .and_modify(|val| *val += 1)
                .or_insert(0)
        });
    hm
}
```

But the compiler complains with

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
 --> src/lib.rs:7:26
  |
7 |         .map(|word| word.trim_end_matches(char::is_ascii_punctuation))
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                          |
  |                          expected signature of `fn(char) -> _`
  |                          found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> _`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> bool {std::char::methods::<impl char>::is_ascii_punctuation}`
```

I can't make out what the error really means or how my usage differs from that in the docs for [`trim_end_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end_matches): `assert_eq!("123foo1bar123".trim_end_matches(char::is_numeric), "123foo1bar");`

Comment: In addition to my answer, I would recommend changing the final `map` to a `for` loop. It is not really good style to put side effects in a `map` function, and it leads to problems with borrowing, which are unnecessary here. Here is how I would fix it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd45cf27e26e150f6eb0247fac3198be

Comment: @PeterHall thank you for the suggestion. I was just trying that approach after reading your answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, `trim_end_matches` expects the argument to be a function that takes a `char`, but `char::is_ascii_punctuation` takes its argument by reference.

You can just add a closure to convert:

```
.map(|word| word.trim_end_matches(|c| char::is_ascii_punctuation(&c)))
```

---

Most predicate methods on `char` (e.g. `is_alphanumerc`) take `self` but, for historical backwards-compatibility reasons (see [RFC comments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44042#issuecomment-370399951)), the ASCII-specific methods take `&self`. For non-ASCII methods you could just do, for example:

```
.map(|word| word.trim_end_matches(char::is_alphanumeric))
```

Comment: I've just looked at the signature for `char::is_numeric` vs `char::is_ascii_punctuation` and the former takes `self` while the latter takes `&self`.  As to specifically why all the ascii methods for `char` take `&self` rather than `self`, I have no idea. Especially as the methods all seem to dereference `self` in the function body.